# A blender that cans preserves to jars?

Tags: food-preservation, jam, stand-mixer, pickles

Do blenders exist that can cook and mix food so that it ends up in steamed jars automatically?

Comment: We don't answer questions about why companies aren't selling something. I had to roll back your question to its first version, to stay within scope.

Comment: There are gadgets for home cooks on the market that can do all steps up to, but not including the final fill-in-jars-and-process. An example that’s been rather successful in Germany: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermomix

Comment: High-speed blenders such as Vitamix or Blendtec frequently advertise the ability to cook food that they are blending, e.g. for soups. I don't know if they get hot enough for long enough to safely use for canning (it's generally not advised to run the blenders at full tilt for too long as it can reduce their longevity) but I can confirm that stuff "cooked" with those blenders can be pretty steamy once I take off the lid.